# How set value of input programmatically? Problem: value disappear on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, aliexpress

I want to set value of input using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("mobileNo").focus();
document.getElementById("mobileNo").select();
document.getElementById("mobileNo").value = "123456789";
```

Unfortunately when I click on input field my value disappear. Can you help me with this?

---

Without clicking on input:

```
<div class="phone-text"><span data-meta="Field" class="next-input next-large"><input id="mobileNo" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobileNo" height="100%" autocomplete="off" value="" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.placeorder.0.74328" aria-label="error"></span></div>
```

After click on input:

```
<div class="phone-text"><span data-meta="Field" class="next-input next-focus next-large"><input id="mobileNo" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobileNo" height="100%" autocomplete="off" value="" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.placeorder.0.74328" aria-label="error"></span></div
```

As you can see after click on input there is added class "next-focus", maybe it is problem with that?

---

I want to use it on aliexpress address form:

[SCREEN HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d60pp.png)

Comment: Do you have a click event listener? Are you using a framework that adds its own listeners?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know, I want to use it on aliexpress address form :)

Comment: Similar question to above: do you have any wrappers / UI frameworks that change the appearance of the input?  (did you add the div/span/input yourself or where they created by some framework)

Comment: @freedomn-m check screenshot in topic

Comment: Added AliExpress tag - perhaps there's someone following that tag that knows how forms are created.

Comment: It sounds like their library is doing this.

Comment: @Barmar please create account and check it :)

Comment: @freedomn-m probably not

Comment: Create an account on a chinese shopping site just to help you with your question?  No thanks :P